# Join 4 tables with specified column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have this code:

```
SELECT A.UNITCODE, B.FORMATIONCODE, C.UPPERFORMATIONCODE, D.UPPERFORMATIONCODE 
FROM UNIT AS A.UNITCODE 
INNER JOIN FORMATION AS B.FORMATIONCODE 
INNER JOIN UPPERFORMATION_UNIT AS C.UPPERFORMATION 
INNER JOIN UPPERFORMATION AS D.UPPERFORMATIONCODE 
WHERE UNITCODE='7000007'
```

Can you guys help me how to join 4 tables with specified column?

Comment: show how the tables are related  .. which column values must macth for join  ?

Comment: For joining you need to show all 4 tables relation.

Answer (score 1):

Assuiming  the all 3 related  tables have the same UNIT_ID for join with table UNIT

```
  SELECT 
        A.UNITCODE
      , B.FORMATIONCODE
      , C.UPPERFORMATIONCODE
      , D.UPPERFORMATIONCODE 
  FROM UNIT AS A 
  INNER JOIN FORMATION AS B ON B.FORMATIONCODE  = A.UNIT_ID
  INNER JOIN UPPERFORMATION_UNIT AS C. C.UPPERFORMATION  = A.UNIT_ID
  INNER JOIN UPPERFORMATION AS D D.UPPERFORMATIONCODE  = A.UNIT_ID
  WHERE UNITCODE='7000007'
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are confusing table aliases and linking columns.

This is how to give a table an alias name in the query in order to enhance readability:

```
INNER JOIN formation AS f
```

where the `AS` is optional. Most often it is ommited.

This is how to join:

```
FROM unit AS u
INNER JOIN upperformation_unit AS ufu ON ufu.unitcode = u.unitcode
```

Well, I don't know the columns linking the tables of course, let alone their names. But I suppose the query would have to look like this more or less:

```
SELECT 
  u.unitcode,
  f.formationcode,
  uf.upperformationcode,
  ufu.upperformationcode 
FROM unit u
JOIN upperformation_unit ufu ON ufu.unitcode = u.unitcode
JOIN upperformation uf ON uf.upperformationcode = ufu.upperformationcode
JOIN formation f ON f.formationcode uf.formationcode
WHERE u.unitcode = 7000007;
```